# Difference of these two First Order Logic statements

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

1) $(\forall x)(\exists y)x{\le}y$

2) $(\exists y)(\forall x)x{\le}y$

Assume that the domain of the variable is $D={0,1,2,...,99}$

These two statements says two things in natural language. I just cannot distinguish two translations.
Can some one help me?

Comment: I want to write that in english. That's what I want.

Comment: The first one says: "for any number $n$ there is number $m$ (not necessarily distinct form $n$) such that $m$ is greater or equal to $n$".

Comment: The second one says: "there is number $m$ that is greater or equal to every number $n$".

Comment: For me, both gives the same meaning. What's the difference? For given domain which is correct and which is not? Please explain.

Comment: Consider as domain the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers: do you think that the second holds ?

Comment: Isn't 99 helps to hold that? "There exists at least one number" right? So isn't that true? Please enlighten me.

Comment: @User9125: Yes $99$ is called the witness for (2). After you give me $y = 99$, no matter what $x$ I give to you, ...

Comment: @User9125: Mauro was simply telling you a particular domain where (2) fails to hold. This should be easy to see using the game interpretation I described in my answer.

Comment: And for me, it seems that 99 helps to hold first one too?

Comment: You can try with a simpler example, avoiding the complications related to aithmetic. "every husband has married a wife ..." compared to: "there is an husband that married all the wifes..."

Comment: But if X was husband, how did you take "there is a husband " in second sentence? It should be "every husband " in there too right?

Comment: Oh wow. Now I get it. Thank you very much @Mauro. Thanks for that explanation.^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"$\forall x\ ( P(x) )$" means "For any $x$, it is true that $P(x)$", equivalently "$P(x)$ is true for every $x$". If you claim this statement, then you're effectively claiming that:

> No matter what $x$ I give you, you can show me that $P(x)$ is true.

"$\exists x\ ( P(x) )$" means "For some $x$, it is true that $P(x)$", equivalently "$P(x)$ is true for at least one $x$". If you claim this statement, then you're effectively claiming that:

> You can give me some $x$ and then show me that $P(x)$ is true.

What you have asked about is better written in the form:

> $\forall x\ ( \exists y\ ( P(x,y) ) )$.
>
> $\exists y\ ( \forall x\ ( P(x,y) ) )$.

It should be clear from my definition that they say different things. You should slowly expand the quantifiers one by one to see why. For example the first one expands to:

> For any $x$, it is true that $\exists y\ ( P(x,y) )$.

and then:

> For any $x$, it is true that ( for some $y$, it is true that $P(x,y)$ ).

which if you claim it means that:

> No matter what $x$ I give you, you can give me some $y$ and then show me that $P(x,y)$ is true.

Note that the $y$ that you give me is **after** I give you the $x$, so you are free to choose a different $y$ if I give you a different $x$.

In contrast the second expands to:

> For some $y$, it is true that $\forall x\ ( P(x,y) )$.

and then:

> For some $y$, it is true that ( for every $x$, it is true that $P(x,y)$ ).

which if you claim it means that:

> You can give me some $y$ and then show me that, no matter what $x$ I give you, you can show me that $P(x,y)$ is true.

Note that the $y$ that you give me is **before** I give you the $x$, so that single $y$ must work for every $x$ that I give you.

Comment: Unless you know what you're doing, don't write the quantifiers the way you've been doing it. The way I've written it is not only completely precise as to what is **under** the scope of each quantifier, but also is a common convention and will be universally understood.

Comment: Sorry. This doesn't make any sense for me. Can you simply explain with natural english which is true and which is false for given domain D? I spent lots of hours to understand this and This still gives me no sense at all.

Comment: @User9125: I've fully expanded the definitions, and added one useful way of understanding quantifiers. If it is still unclear, tell me specifically which point in my answer you get lost. The point is that once you grasp the quantifiers in full generality, it will be trivial for you to understand all instances, so I don't want to be bogged down by your specific example.

Comment: Both meanings which I get after translation seems so equal to me. Can you tell me clearly what's the difference clearly.

Comment: @User9125: I've already explained the difference using the game interpretation. Please think through it slowly. Play the game with an imaginary opponent, using the domain of natural numbers. If you can ensure a win, then the claim is true. If your opponent can ensure a win, then the claim is false.

Comment: @User9125: The **order** of the actions in the game is the key to the difference, which I have already highlighted in bold.

Comment: Thank you very much @User21820 . You are awesome. ^_^

Comment: @User9125: You're welcome! I'm always glad to help. You will find that this game interpretation will be very useful. In this particular case you can easily see that if "$\exists y\ ( \forall x\ ( P(x,y) ) )$" is true then "$\forall x\ ( \exists y\ ( P(x,y) ) )$" is true (because if you can win the game in the first case you can clearly win the game in the second case too), but the reverse does not hold. You should always remember this fact about quantifier order, as you will see this everywhere (like uniform continuity, uniform convergence, ...).